# Tropos literarios

Tags: neologismos

Estoy buscando el equivalente correcto del inglés "literary trope". Una búsqueda sumaria sugiere

a) "cliché literario", que no es correcto porque lleva la connotación de sobreuso.

b) "tropo literario", que me provoca duda pues no existe con ese sentido en el DRAE.

Sin embargo, la segunda opción parece dominar en sitios web (aunque no en discusiones académicas). Esta opción es la que me interesa como objeto de esta pregunta.

Entonces, ¿es un ejemplo de traducción forzada del inglés y que terminará siendo incorporada al léxico? ¿o existe otra expresión correcta que nadie usa por ser un poco erudita?

Comment: Puedes por favor incluir una definición o referencia a lo que se refiere el concepto inglés _literary trope_, o algunos ejemplos tal vez. Yo conozco los tropos literarios en español (metáfora, metonimia...), pero mirando en internet noté que en inglés puede ser un poco ambiguo. (¿Tópicos, motivos, leitmotiv, temas...?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La palabra *cliché* dependiendo del ámbito suele venir acompañada de una connotación negativa, más que recurrente es *falto de creatividad*.

Según la explicación dada en la pregunta, veo más adecuada la frase *recurso literario*.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo hay [dos acepciones](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trope) principales. Una es *cliché*, pero la más usada es **figura retórica**, **figura literaria**, que seguramente sea por la que estás preguntando. Aún así, es raro utilizar ese término al menos en español, sobre todo si se puede aclarar cuál es la figura literaria a la que se recurrió. De ser posible, preferiría especificarlo—es analogía, parábola, metáfora, alegoría, etc.

Y en cuanto a **tropo**, sí que en el DRAE está la acepción:

> 2. m. Ret. Empleo de una palabra en sentido distinto del que propiamente le corresponde, pero que tiene con este alguna conexión, correspondencia o semejanza. La metáfora, la metonimia y la sinécdoque son tipos de tropos.

Pero al parecer refiere a cierto tipo de figuras literarias—se exluiría al *hipérbaton*, entre otras—por lo que será intercambiable en algunos casos.